# Framework for data synchronization into phonegap app

Tags: software-development, synchronization

I have data in a SQL Server database which can be accessed via .NET WebAPI and is delivered as JSON.

I have a phonegap app running on Android, iOS and WP8 that should use parts of this data, even in offline mode.

With which frameworks can one achieve just-in-time synchronization of the relevant data betweeen device and server?

As of now, I have found the following:

- Couchbase Mobile
- RhoMobile RhoConnect
- AppearIQ DataSync

but with none of them I am completely sure that the synchronization also works when the app is in the background, and even if the app has not yet been started after the phone has been switched off and on again.

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) is a complete framework which is designed to synchronise data between client and server.

Excert from http://blog.jasoncrawford.org/meteor-demystified

> Meteor’s central goal
>
> To understand Meteor you need to understand its central goal, which
>   drives the design.
>
> The core problem Meteor solves is a data synchronization problem. Your
>   webapp is a distributed system, with data on both client and server.
>   The main challenge is to synchronize the data instantly and seamlessly
>   between the two—and more, to synchronize all clients with each other.
>   Ideally it should appear to all users that they are interacting
>   directly with a single, shared store of data.

This does rely on mongodb though.  So it depends if you can rework your backend to use this to synchronise everything.

(Please note I haven't used this framework my self I have attended quite a few sessions on it's use and seems to fit)

Comment: Thanks, interesting suggestion, I never heard it before and will definitely look into it!